# DataProc MapReduce stopped working

Tags: hadoop, hbase, bigtable, google-cloud-dataproc

I run standard hbase class for counting rows (RowCounter) in a BigTable table. DataProc gui in Google Console is used.
It worked fine, but after few weeks I tried to run similar jar and
job fails due hardly explainable reason.
This don't look like connection parameter issue, because if I use 
non existing Hbase table name it understand this.

Outcome is the same for 1.1.2 and 1.0.1.1 Hbase clients.
1.0.1.1 is from example.
I discovered that 1.1.2 version is used by cluster which is setup by bdutils.

```
6/02/08 14:35:34 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
16/02/08 14:35:34 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1454940934781_0001_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.io.IOException: Cannot create a record reader because of a previous error. Please look at the previous logs lines from the task's full log for more details.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormatBase.createRecordReader(TableInputFormatBase.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.<init>(MapTask.java:515)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:758)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The input format instance has not been properly initialized. Ensure you call initializeTable either in your constructor or initialize method
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormatBase.getTable(TableInputFormatBase.java:585)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormatBase.createRecordReader(TableInputFormatBase.java:169)
    ... 8 more
```

Answer (score 3):

Dataproc clusters created before ~now had weekly JVM auto updates enabled. One of these updates broke compatibility with the ALPN-boot jar used by the Bigtable client library.

A rollout has completed that will update the default versions of the JVM and the ALPN jar to again be compatible. In order to make use of the fixed images, you'll need to start a new cluster.

If you need to perform an in-place fix, you can update the copy of ALPN-boot.jar on all nodes in your cluster which is located under /usr/local/share/google/alpn. See this table for version compatibility http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/alpn-chapter.html#alpn-versions